# React & MUI: Unable to style MUI Icon with makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to style mui Icons using `className` attribute, however it doesn't work. But when I'm applying inline styles it works as expected. I will have a few Icons in the component which I want to style the same way that's why I don't want to use inline styles and copy the same code several times. What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help?

```
import React from 'react';
import FacebookIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Facebook';
import TwitterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Twitter';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        fontSize: '50px',
        margin: '10px',
        color: 'primary'
    }
});

const Links = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return(
        <div>
            //this doesn't work
            <TwitterIcon className={classes.root} />

            //this works
            <FacebookIcon sx= {{ fontSize:'50px', margin:'10px', color:'primary' }} />  
        </div>
    );
}

export default Links;
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use the classes prop to override classes. or you need to be more specific in the class itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeStyles` is legacy API that relies on JSS, *not* emotion. It should not be used unless you are supporting older versions of Mui.

The recommended way is to either use `styled` or specify variants in the `theme` object.

```js
import { styled } from '@mui/material'

const SocialMediaIcon = styled(Icon)(({ theme }) => ({
  fontSize: 50,
  margin: 10,
  color: theme.palette.text.primary,
}))

<SocialMediaIcon component={TwitterIcon} />
```

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiIcon: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'social' },
          style: {
            fontSize: 50,
            margin: 10,
            color: 'primary',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
})

<Icon variant="social" component={Instagram} />
```

[Demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-unable-to-style-mui-icon-with-makestyles-s7vi4)